# Confusion with CSS absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to center this circle on an empty page using CSS absolute positioning, but for some reason it is off, as is the centering of the little dot inside of my larger circle.

Any advice or clarification would be great!

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
 <html>
 <body>
    <div id="circle">
            <div id="center"></div>
        </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
 #circle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 10%;
    border-color: tan;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

#center {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center vertically and horizontally, add the following css:

```
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfn4t263/

The issue was occuring because even though you specified `left: 50%`, it calculates this from the left most edge of the div...so the left most edge of your circle. This means your circle will appear skewed to the right.

(Works on IE8 upwards...in case you were wondering.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have answered it myself!

The divs are off center because I use percentages to scale their location. As a result, their fixed sizes throw off the positioning set by the percentages.

E.g. is the fixed size of the circle was 0, it would be center.

All the best!

Comment: Yes vertically or horizontally centering a positioned element you need two 50% attributes: 50% of the container and 50% of the element. Top, right, bottom, and left all move the element 50% of the container's size. Transform will move the element 50% of the elements size however. So typical code would be `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)`. Though I typically use `translate3d` for performance reasons incase I animate the property.